# Is there a way to determine total number of upvotes and downvotes (etc) for a user (regardless of reputation cap)?

Tags: feature-request, api, reputation, reputation-audit

For example, if you use the `/users/<id>/reputation` call, you get a list of reputation changes for the user, but it takes the daily reputation cap into account. What I would like is an API call where I can get data similar to what's returned when you go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. That page gives you something like this:

```
change_type | question_id | reputation
2           | 2422782     | (10)
3           | 2422162     | (-2) 
2           | 2422150     | (2)
2           | 2416148     | [0]
1           | 2414761     | [15]
1           | 2413758     | [15]
```

So I could use the change_type column to determine the "uncapped" reputation change for the user in the given period. For example, in the example above, they got an upvote, then a downvote, then another upvote - but it was capped to 2, then another upvote (capped again, so it's 0), then two accepted answers, 15 each and not affected by the cap.

So while their capped reputation change was 40, we can work out that if the cap had not been in place, their "uncapped" reputation change would have been 58.

Is there (or if not, *should* there be) a way to get the same sort of info from the API?

**Edit**

I could do it with a call to `/users/<id>/questions` and `/users/<id>/answers` but I would not be able to get the reputation changes for questions asked/answered in the past.

Comment: See: [Can more vote-related data be added to the user object?](http://stackapps.com/q/4310/11890)

Answer (score 3):

Kevin indeed misinterpreted your question as per your comment on his answer - as such it has been a valid [`feature-request`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) in principle and I've retagged it accordingly (you might adjust the title a bit to better reflect the use case, i.e. *audit the individual reputation changes*).

That said, I fully expect (and support) this to be [`status-declined`](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-declined) for privacy reasons, because otherwise voting wouldn't be completely anonymous anymore (down votes show up in the voters audit trail) - consequently the [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) you mentioned is only available to a user personally, i.e. it is not possible to audit other users reputation as well (see [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) for some background, though it doesn't address the privacy argument).

Answer (score 1):

[`/users/{id}`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1?help)

`up_vote_count` and `down_vote_count`

Comment: That is, similar to what `http://stackoverflow.com/reputation` returns.

Comment: Related: [How to get up_vote_count and down_vote_count for a user?](http://stackapps.com/q/6282/11890)