# Reputation API to display a reputation history

Tags: support, api-v2, reputation

I'm building something similar to the reputation graph / summary on the SO user page.

[image: rep]

The [answer](https://stackapps.com/a/1484/2838) explains that the `/users/{ids}/reputation` API method gives a sum of reputation for the period.  So querying for the start/end of 14-Apr-2011 gives me the +5 rep I see in the screenshot.

[https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/109102/reputation?fromdate=**1334361600**&todate=**1334448000**&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/109102/reputation?fromdate=1334361600&todate=1334448000&site=stackoverflow)

The screenshot graph runs from 14-Apr-2011 to 16-Mar-2011.  To build something similar I think I'll have to hit a URL with the date boundaries for each day in the range.  Is this right, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty hard to reproduce that graph using the API unfortunately.  The data that backs it is a fairly recent addition to the sites, that was under serious revision when API V2.0 was being designed so it's not directly exposed.

The best approximation available is that pretty nasty query plan, yes.  Some better data is planned for the next API release now that the actual implementation of reputation has settled down some.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I'm about to build the graph in a wp7 app.  Maybe i'll do it in server side code until the new api becomes available.