# How to get up_vote_count and down_vote_count for a user?

Tags: support, api, api-v2, users, voting

I'm testing the following command:

```
$ curl -s "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/55075?&site=stackoverflow" | gunzip -d | python -m json.tool
```

However it doesn't return `up_vote_count` and `down_vote_count` values as suggested [in this old answer](https://stackapps.com/a/659/11890).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Note that that old answer was for API version 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that returns those properties. The default filter does not.

Also, the API is at version 2.2. You should use that unless you've a very good reason not to.

So try, for example:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/55075?site=stackoverflow&filter=!G*ky*lRuarbDJTpnwEtY-a05oz
```

Or:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/55075?site=stackoverflow&filter=!-*f(6q0h9HBe
```

For your URL.

For more information about easily creating custom filters, see [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653).